# Are these two integrals equal to each other in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: probability, integration

Let $p(x)$, $p(y)$, and $p(x, y)$ be three density functions: the first one for a random variable $X$, the second one for a random variable $Y$, and the last one for $(X, Y)$. There is no independence assumption made.

Is it true that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}p(x)p(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}p(x, y) = 1\text{?}$$
My thought is that by definition,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}p(x, y) = 1$$
but I'm less certain about the other integral. I seem to think that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}p(x)p(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}p(x)\cdot\int_{\mathbb{R}}p(y)=1 \cdot 1 = 1\text{.}$$
This seems like it's ridiculously easy, hence why me (and my two peers) have been doubting ourselves. (Or maybe it's just a late night.)

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar However, if they *aren't* independent, are the integrals still equal? Note: there is no independence assumption made

Comment: Sorry about that, need to know if $p(x,y)$ is the joint probability distribution? or $p(x,y) =p(x)p(y)$

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar Yes, $p(x, y)$ is the joint distribution.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar Note I said in the question: **There is no independence assumption made.** You cannot assume that $p(x, y) = p(x)p(y)$.

Comment: Okay then the $p(x,y)= p(x)p(y) $ if they are independent. In which case when you integrate, the $p(x),p(y)$ being functions of purely $x,y$, variable separate and they both integrate to $1$. In that case that they aren't independent you have $p(x,y)\neq p(x)p(y)$. But $p(x,y)$ will still integrate to 1 over $\mathbb{R}^2$ by definition but the variable separation argument isn't necessarily true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrals are equal. If $(X,Y)$ has a joint density $p(x,y)$, then the marginal density of $X$ is defined as $p_X(x):=\int_y p(x,y)\,dy$. Note that $\int_x p_X(x)\,dx=1$, since it's the same as $\int_x\int_y p(x,y)\,dy\,dx$, which equals $\iint p(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ by Fubini. Similarly $\int_yp_Y(y)\,dy=1$. So we have
$$
\iint p(x,y)\,dx\,dy = 1 = 1\cdot 1 =\int_x p_X(x)\,dx \int_y p_Y(y)\,dy=\iint p_X(x)p_Y(y)\,dx\,dy,
$$
again invoking Fubini for the last equality.

Comment: This looks right, not what I put in my now deleted "answer". +1.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to prove this:

As stated, by definition of a joint distribution density function,

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} p(x,y)  = 1$.

Note that this makes no assumption of independence. On the other hand, supposing that we know that $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ are valid marginal distributions, then we note that there exists **a** valid joint distribution in which $X'$ and $Y'$ have density function $p(x)$ and $p(y)$, but are independent. By definition of independence, the density for this joint distribution will be

$p(x,y) = p(x) p(y)$.

Then just applying the first rule from above, since this is a valid joint distribution, it must integrate to 1. Therefore, if $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ are valid density functions, then

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} p(x)p(y)  = 1$.